# Add prefix to import urls after compiling typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an angular2 app, which I am writing in typescript.

I'm wondering if it is possible to make the typescript compiler add a prefix (and postfix) to all imported urls?

E.g. I got the following code:

```
import {AppComponent} from 'app.component';
```

Which is compiled into something like this in javascript:

```
System.register(['./test/app.component'], ...
```

But what I want is:

```
System.register(['<some_path>/test/app.component.js'], ...
```

Where "some_path" could be e.g. "component/my_app/".